# Adding multiple colors to an object without assigning them

Tags: modifiers

I want my object to be able to have multiple color choices to choose from, but I don't want to make it multicolored by assigning the colors to different faces. Like, say I made a ring, and I wanted people to be able to choose what color they want it to be. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can add as many material as you want and change the active material whenever you choose.

[image: changing materials]

You click the <kbd>+</kbd> button next to the material name to create a new material.

You will want to make sure you click the <kbd>F</kbd> so that is highlighted, this creates a fake user that ensures the material is saved with the file. Normally unused materials will not get saved.